# How to wait for function to stop before calling it again

Tags: javascript, function, promise, timing, calling-convention

I have had trouble trying to get my function to finish before calling it again. This is my code now:

```js
function TypeAnimation(str, time)
{    
    var text = document.getElementById('loading');

    for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        let k = i;
        setTimeout(function(){
            text.innerHTML += str.charAt(i); 
        }, time * (k + 1));
    }
}

function StartGame()
{
    TypeAnimation('first line of text', 50)
    TypeAnimation('next line of text but slower', 100)
}

window.onload = StartGame;
```

When doing this I get the output as **finrset xlitne olf itenxte of text but slower**.

I have tried promises by using the following code:

```js
function TypeAnimation(str, time)
{    
    return new Promise((resolve) => {

        var text = document.getElementById('loading');

        for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
            let k = i;
            setTimeout(function(){
                text.innerHTML += str.charAt(i); 
            }, time * (k + 1));
        }

        resolve();
    });
}

function StartGame()
{
    TypeAnimation('first line of text', 50).then(TypeAnimation('next line of text but slower', 100))
}

window.onload = StartGame;
```

But when I do this I still get the same result

On top of this, I also tried the same thing but with with a different StartGame()

```
async function StartGame()
{
    await TypeAnimation('first line of text', 50)
    TypeAnimation('next line of text but slower', 100)
}
```

Once again, the same issue arises and I get the same output

If it helps, this is all created with an electron js app.

Comment: [events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events) are one way to do such operations, you can send an event when the action is finished and you can listen for that event to start it again as an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't work, because you resolve the promise before timeouts even happen

The approach like this will make it easier

```js
async function TypeAnimation(str, time) {
  const text = document.getElementById('loading');

  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    text.innerHTML += str.charAt(i);
    await wait(time)
  }
}

async function StartGame() {
  await TypeAnimation('first line of text', 50)
  await TypeAnimation('next line of text but slower', 100)
}

StartGame()

function wait(time) {
  return new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, time))
}
```

```html
<span id="loading"></span>
```